# without sending any email how can i know that the email address is real and existing email address

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter framework.i want to verify email address which is inputted by  users.Actually i want to be sure that the inputted email address is real and existing email address without sending any email.is it possible?if it is possible please help me.I want to do it using codeigniter framework.
Thank you.

Comment: By "valid" you mean real and existing, or just well-formed? (for the latter, there's the validation class)

Comment: it means real and existing email address.:-)

Answer (score 2):

There's not going to be a way to confirm that an email address exists and is actually used by someone without sending an email to them to confirm it. Even if it doesn't bounce, that doesn't mean it's "real", it might just be forwarded to another address, silently discarded, or any number of things.

Comment: Unfortunately this is correct, because - well, SPAM. All you can do is send an email and have a person click a link/respond to the email to confirm it's at least potentially real (see Mailinator.com for why I say 'potentially'), and you can see if it's "well-formed" to make sure it could even possibly exist. The only exception to this is Outlook Exchange servers, where if you have an account they can be configured to validate email addresses against their own domain; but that isn't applicable to the general case, so can be ignored.